# How to use DI in this example?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-webjobssdk

I followed this example https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started and it is working fine. What I want to do is to make the connection strings (strongly typed) available in all methods within Functions class. My Connection Strings object:

```
namespace MyApp.Domain
{
  public class Secrets
  {
    public class ConnectionStrings
    {
      public string SqlServer {get; set;}
      public string Storage {get; set;}
      public string SendGrid {get; set;}
      public string AzureWebJobsDashboard { get; set; }
      public string AzureWebJobsStorage {get; set;}
    }
  }
}
```

In web project I use (and it works perfectly):

```
services.Configure<Secrets.ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("CUSTOMCONNSTR_ConnectionStrings"));
```

and in the classes' constructors I use:

```
public class EmailController: ControllerBase
  {
    private readonly MyEmail _myEmail;

    public EmailController(MyEmail MyEmail)
    {
      _myEmail = MyEmail;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> SendEmail()
    {
      try
      {
        ...

        return await _myEmail.SendMailMI3D(myMsg);
      }
      catch (System.Exception ex)
      {
          return ex.Message + " - " + ex.StackTrace;
      }
    }

    [HttpGet("sendgrid")]
    public string GetSendGrid(long id)
    {
      return _myEmail.SendGridConnStr();
    }
  }
```

But this way doesn't work on webjobs (console apps).

I tried to insert a simple Console.WriteLine in Functions' constructor but it doesn't work as well. So I think this is the problem: Functions' constructor is not being called. So when I insert a message in my queue I receive this error message related to DI Connection String:

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can anybody please help me? Thanks a lot.

```
public Functions(IOptions<Secrets.ConnectionStrings> ConnectionStrings)
    {
      _connectionStrings = ConnectionStrings;

      Console.WriteLine("Simple line");
      Console.WriteLine($"Functions constructor: ${_connectionStrings.Value.SendGrid}");
    }
```

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection is available in WebJobs but you do need to take the extra step to [create an IJobActivator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2018/08/22/webjobs-in-azure-with-net-core-2-1/) to define the injection.

```
namespace NetCoreWebJob.WebJob
{
    public class JobActivator : IJobActivator
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider services;

        public JobActivator(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            this.services = services;
        }

        public T CreateInstance<T>()
        {
            return services.GetService<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `Main()`

```
var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.JobActivator = new JobActivator(services.BuildServiceProvider());
```

That should allow the runtime to utilize the parameterized constructor.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The Functions' constructor was not called. Thanks anyway... I'll keep trying...

Comment: JobHostConfiguration doesn't exist on Webjobs sdk 3.x

Comment: you also have to register the class you want dependencies resolved for - so if you want IOptions resolved in class Functions, you need to also register Functions class